# BCP Utility vs SQL Server compatibility

Tags: sql-server, bcp, bulk-import

I am planning to use the BCP utility for bulk import & export from SQL Server. So just want to know if is there a **compatibility matrix of versions between  BCP Utility & SQL Server**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not and there is not need: bcp will be fine.

Only be careful with "Native Data File Support". From documentation:

> In SQL Server, the bcp utility supports native data files compatible
> with SQL Server versions starting with SQL Server 2000 (8.x) and
> later.

And, of course, you must have compatible data types.

I did this a ton of times.

Comment: Does it mean, the latest BCP utility will be compatible with SQL Server 2008 and higher?

Comment: Not from a data file format perspective - it supports native format files all the way back to SQL Server 2000. However, the latest BCP Utility uses ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server - depending on the specific version that it actually installs you will find the minimum supported SQL Server versions to be either 2008 and 2008R2 (17.3 and earlier) or SQL Server 2012 (17.4 and later). Ref: [System requirements, installation, and driver files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files)